# php code works with mamp but not on ubuntu server

Tags: php, session, ubuntu, twitter, mamp

I have start looking at a twitter php library http://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth, but i can't get it to work on my ubuntu server, but on my mac, with mamp it works without any problems.

This is the code that don't won't to work on my server, but in mamp. Yes i have edit config file

```
<?php

/* Start session and load library. */
session_start();
require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
require_once('config.php');

/* Build TwitterOAuth object with client credentials. */
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);

/* Get temporary credentials. */
$request_token = $connection->getRequestToken(OAUTH_CALLBACK);

/* Save temporary credentials to session. */
$_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $token = $request_token['oauth_token'];
$_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];

/* If last connection failed don't display authorization link. */
switch ($connection->http_code) {
  case 200:
    /* Build authorize URL and redirect user to Twitter. */
    $url = $connection->getAuthorizeURL($token);
    header('Location: ' . $url); 
    break;
  default:
    /* Show notification if something went wrong. */
    echo 'Could not connect to Twitter. Refresh the page or try again later.';
}
```

I have enable php session on my ubuntu server, because this code works

```
<?php
       session_start();
       $_SESSION["secretword"] = "hello there";
       $secretword = $_SESSION["secretword"] ;
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>A PHP Session Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo $secretword; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: turn on error reporting in your scripts:

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

Comment: anything in the logs (/var/log/apache2/* if not configured somewhere else)? what PHP version are you running locally and on the server?

Comment: Did you look at the error logs? /var/log/apache2/error.log (or maybe that directory contains per-virtualhost errors).

Comment: on the server i use Version 5.3.2-1 and on mamp Version 5.2.11

one error that i think is the problem

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init() in /var/www/blomman/projects/test/ab/twitteroauth/twitteroauth.ph
p on line 199, referer:xxx

but i have install curl? or do have install something else? (apt-get install curl)

Comment: aha, php5-curl was the problem

Comment: anyway, the way you tested the session is wrong, it will always succeed even if your sessions don't work. Instead, test this way:
<?php
       session_start();
       $_SESSION["secretword"] = "hello there";
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>A PHP Session Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="continue.php">continue</a>
</body>
</html>

continue.php:
<?php
       session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>A PHP Session Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo $_SESSION["secretword"]; ?>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have curl installed - for ubuntu should be as easy as `sudo apt-get install curl`

Also turn your PHP errors on `ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);` if you're not getting any clues from error messages.

Comment: this was going to be my answer. :)